# Issue with Multi Transclude in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using multitranscldue in angular js.I am having a directive like below.

```
(function(){

    angular.module("MyDirective",['multi-transclude'])
    .directive("myDirective",function(){
        var MyLink = function(scope,element,attr){
            scope.title = attr.title;
        }
        return{
             restrict : 'EA',
            scope: {title:"="},
             transclude:true,
             templateUrl:"directive.html",
             link: MyLink
        }
    });
}())
```

The html for directive is like

```
<div >
    <div>
        <span data-ng-bind="title"></span>
        <div ng-multi-transclude="card-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my main html class, I am using the directive like below.

```
<my-directive title="asdasdas">
        <div name="card-body">
            {{title}}
            </div>
        </my-directive>
```

I am getting an error like

Error: Illegal use of ngMultiTransclude. No wrapping controller.

Please help me with this.

The link to plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2aMBVao2FbV1chG7qpI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `ng-multi-transclude-controller` to your directive's HTML template, as follows:

```
<div ng-multi-transclude-controller>
    <div>
        <span data-ng-bind="title"></span>
        <div ng-multi-transclude="card-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```